# Angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.14 and addin external node modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

After the Ng2 release announced, I wanted to put hands into it and I wanted to use redux with it.

Actually, I m having some troubles when installing redux-thunk, because it doesn't have a d.ts file associated inside of the module.

Before the last release of angular-cli, we were adding some stuff in a file called "angular-cli.build", that has disappeared now.

This way, I dont know at all how to add my external modules inside of my project if they doesn't contain d.ts files.

I m pretty sure that I have to deal with the anular-cli.json file, but I don't know how.

Clearly, I need to install third party libs that are not typescript (directly) compatible

Does anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to link external modules/libs in `angular-cli.json` - `app[0]/scripts` array. Just specify a relative path to the JS file and it gets linked into the `index.html`.